# Callout Limits within Batch Apex

Tags: batch, callout

How to use the batch to send more than 10 emails using callout.
I've done a class batch that contains a start that has the query, an execute that has the sendEmail and a finish that has nothing but this is due to that does not work.

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
         return   Database.getQueryLocator(query)} 
      global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope) { 
            SES sesEmail = new SES(as3.key,as3.secret); 
             for(sObject s: scope){ 
                sesEmail.sendEmail(subRecipients,sender,subject,newBody); 
        } 
  //update scope; }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post some code. There's nothing here that says why you're having a problem.

Comment: ok, this is my code:
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {return Database.getQueryLocator(query)}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope) {
            SES sesEmail = new SES(as3.key,as3.secret);
            for(sObject s: scope){
                 sesEmail.sendEmail(subRecipients,sender,subject,newBody);
            }
            //update scope;
    }